# Specifying linear model in R without an intercept with contrasts

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying run a linear model in R that does not specify an intercept. The reason is to eventually calculate the sums of squares reduced when an intercept is added. However, I am receiving different results when specifying this model using built-in factor contrasts versus explicitly stating the contrast values (i.e., -.5 and .5).

More specifically, using `contrasts()` results in a model with 2 terms (no intercept) while explicitly stating the contrast values via a column vector results in the correct model (no intercept and 1 term specifying the contrast).

```r
group <- rep(c("c", "t"), each = 5)
group_cont <- rep(c(-.5, .5), each = 5)
var1 <- runif(10)
var2 <- runif(10)

test_data <- data.frame(
  group = factor(group), 
  group_cont = group_cont,
  y = var1, 
  x = var2
  )
contrasts(test_data$group) <- cbind(grp = c(-.5, .5))

summary(lm(y ~ 1 + group, data = test_data))      # full model
summary(lm(y ~ 0 + group, data = test_data))      # weird results
summary(lm(y ~ 0 + group_cont, data = test_data)) # expected
```

Is there a way to specify a linear model without an intercept, but still use `contrasts()` to specify the contrast?

Answer (score 0):

`lm()` asks for a data frame and column names as inputs. When you use `contrasts()`, you are assigning an attribute to the column in your data frame, which you can call directly using the the `contrast` function or `attr`. However, you are not changing the data type itself. Using you example above:

```
> str(test_data)
  'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ group     : Factor w/ 2 levels "c","t": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 #### still a factor ####
  ..- attr(*, "contrasts")= num [1:2, 1] -0.5 0.5  #### NOTE The contrast attribute ####
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "c" "t"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "grp"
 $ group_cont: num  -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
 $ y         : num  0.161 0.518 0.417 0.335 0.301 ...
 $ x         : num  0.34 0.729 0.766 0.629 0.191 ...

> attr(test_data$group, "contrasts")

   grp
c -0.5
t  0.5
```

So a `attr` was added but the type is still a factor. So `lm` treats it like a factor, providing you a coefficient for each level. Moreover, providing `contrast` or calling the `attr` inside `lm` will throw an error. Depending on what you want to the end to look like, you may need to explore a different package like [contrast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/vignettes/contrast.pdf). There is also a `contrast` argument in `lm` but I am not 100% sure this is what you are really looking for. See `?lm` for more on that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I'm still confused as to why the contrast works properly when specifying the full linear model with the intercept? The only situation in which the contrast seems to not work properly is the model without the intercept.